# Web Application Publish Problem

Tags: asp.net

After publishing website, when i open default web page,it shows source code of asp.net web page instead of page. What should i do? Can you help me in this regard please?

Comment: You're giving us absolutely no information to run on, but, you have to configure the server to consider your web page as an asp.net webpage.

Comment: Can you please show us, what actually you are getting in display of page, when you are trying to access the page.

Comment: Is this on IIS6 or IIS7?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your code is not complied that means its some thing problem with your web server looks like its not running.

Enable ISS and copy your web site folder to the site and run though [localhost](http://127.0.0.1)

Extra : [To Publish Content on your Web Site](http://www.tech-faq.com/configure-iis.shtml)

Comment: Thanks for reply and cooperation, actually by mistake i was using ftp protocol instead of http therefore i was getting source file. Anyhow problem has been solved. Once again thanks.